# Sharepoint web application creation using the object model

Tags: sharepoint, builder

I am using the webapplicationbuilder class to create a new web application and have found many articles that help with this, none however seem to specify how you designate the URL or the application, i just get "sharepoint - 123" where 123 is the port specified and "servername/:123" as the url, whereas i need "http://myserver/.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the [SPWebApplicationBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplicationbuilder.aspx) class.

Have you tried to set the [HostHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplicationbuilder.hostheader.aspx) property of your [SPWebApplicationBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplicationbuilder.aspx) object?

Comment: that wont run if i set it to a new URL, it asks instead for a URI, not quite what im after I dont think, but thanks